# Input parameters are shown in response headers, which is vulnerable to security threats - have to avoid the same

Tags: httpresponse

When the form is posted the input parameters are viwed in response headers, which is vulnerable to security threats. I dont want to show these input parameters in the response header.
Example

POST /genaw/reports/adv/RelatedPartyEdit.jsp HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/xaml+xml, */*
Referer: https://localhost:8002/genaw/reports/adv/RelatedPartyEdit.jsp
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:8002
Content-Length: 265
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONIDmw=ll3bMpLCMPgJYW3XLpZ8LC4n41b8C14VglWlRyQzFhm7DP444nrs!-1676166811; _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONIDmw=kbyAU[zA14srFNxXskf5; JSESSIONIDaw=BQQcMpvBpzDHWNg8B2q22vMRyJWJ07n9lZT3hv7NLLlJXG4ZfvQC!1597653939; _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONIDaw=qD6ZP9yPcM4AGa]NdFxo; JSESSIONIDiw=1JjDMpybh00qK5hJpbBmXdwjWK34py7b57PZv5wp3ZCc9SCzpQ3z!1597653939

**from=&cmd=changepwdaction&orgid=sant&nicknamefilter=&fullnamefilter=&rolefilter=&rpuniqueid=4817&parentRpuniqueid=102&idNum=102&org=sant&advisor=SAN165&nickname=596148956&password=&password2=&fullname=LOZOSEKSH&role=6&iwReportsAllow=2&iwReportsAllow=3&Submit=Update**

I want to hide the parameter values given in bold, else my site can be accessed as localhost:8002/genaw/reports/adv/RelatedPartyEdit.jsp?from=&cmd=changepwdaction&orgid=sant&nicknamefilter=&fullnamefilter=&rolefilter=&rpuniqueid=4817&parentRpuniqueid=102&idNum=102&org=sant&advisor=SAN165&nickname=596148956&password=&password2=&fullname=LOZOSEKSH&role=6&iwReportsAllow=2&iwReportsAllow=3&Submit=Update

How to avoid request parameters in response headers to avoid security threats.

Comment: You look like you have some formatting issues too. You might want to edit your post and try to use the formatting options (I assume quoting or maybe code but that will probably try to colour code it strangely) to make those http headers more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like an http problem to me. It also looks much more like Request headers than response headers. The name/value pairs in bold are just your form elements. If you need these values on the server then you have to either live with the fact they are being sent plain-text, switch to https so that the connection is encrypted or do some encryption of the values yourself. This is quite tricky though of course since any encryption will have to be javascript and thus fully visible to any malicious users.

If you don't need these values on the server then take them out of your form.

Comment: my connection is https only. I have to have thses values in the server, else how the server knows the value(not using any javascript - a straight forward post only). but I dont want these parameter information to be displayed once on the response

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I don't want these parameter information to be displayed on the response". You've given no real indication on how they are being displayed on the response. Also with a https connection the only computers that should be able to read that data are the end points of your https connection so I'm not sure that there is any real security issue here anyway.